# "Error: variable "real" does not exist in the model block" in Stan

Tags: python, stan, pystan

I am following the example code using Stan in Python but it is not compiled because of the syntax error:

```
ValueError: Failed to parse Stan model 'anon_model_ad43313e8b4b0b001a1a5d32da64a34e'. Error message:
SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:

variable "real" does not exist.
  error in 'unknown file name' at line 20, column 9
  -------------------------------------------------
    18: }
    19: model{
    20:     real l1;
                ^
    21:     real l2;   
  -------------------------------------------------
```

And this is the stan code:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pystan
from scipy.stats import uniform, invgauss

stan_code = """
data{
    int<lower=0> N;
    vector[N] Y;
    vector[N] x1;
}
parameters{
    real beta0;
    real beta1;
    real<lower=0> lambda;
}
transformed parameters{
    vector[N] exb;
    vector[N] xb;

    for (i in 1:N) xb[i] = beta0 + beta1 * x1[i];
    for (i in 1:N) exb[i] = exp(xb[i]);
}
model{
    real l1;
    real l2;   
    vector[N] loglike;

    lambda ~ uniform(0.0001, 100);

    for (i in 1:N){
        l1 = 0.5 * (log(lambda) - log(2 * pi() * pow(Y[i], 3)));
        l2 = -lambda*pow(Y[i] - exb[i], 2)/(2 * pow(exb[i], 2) * Y[i]);
        loglike[i] = l1 + l2;
    }
    target += loglike;
}
"""

fit = pystan.stan(model_code=stan_code, data= stan_data, iter=5000, chains=3, warmup=2500, n_jobs=3)
```

Is there any something wrong? I also defined `stan_data` before implementing `stan` function.
I read the Stan manual about the model block and it says it is allowed to declare local variables in the model block...
Please let me know the problems above.

Comment: That is a valid Stan program. You might have an encoding issue or something.

Comment: Ah yes. I found that this is because of pystan module.  It worked well using rstan package in R. Thanks! :)